# Need a tool to monitor apache logs for suspicious requests and ban users via htaccess

Tags: apache-2.2, security, log-files

Do you know any tool that monitors apache logs for suspicious actions (for example, several blocks by mod_security from one IP) and after it blocks this IP using .htaccess?

Comment: Try csf hope this will help cause it blocks the ip for offensive access against mod_security but those IP will blocked in firewall not in htaccess

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at [fail2ban](http://fail2ban.org). Not sure if there is an action to ban via .htaccess, but that can be added in -- if you don't want to ban via iptables.